# Is there a way to represent the interior of a circle with a curve?

Tags: circles

As you already know, the interior of a circle is represented by an inequality. For example,

$$x^2+y^2\leq1$$

for the unit circle. Today I was thinking by myself and I wondered if there is a curve that could represent every point inside of a circle. Maybe with a spiral like this,
[image]

If you can't represent it perfectly with a curve, what would be the closest way to represent it?

This question is asked merely out of curiosity, it may be completely irrelevant or meaningless :)

Comment: Here is a relevant reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve.  The curve can't be one-to-one, but it can be done.

Comment: Why can't it be one-to-one? Isn't the Peano curve one-to-one?

Comment: @Mitch: A continuous bijective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, but $[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2$.  So a space-filling curve such as the Peano curve, which is continuous and surjective, cannot be one-to-one.

Comment: @Jonas, @Noah: thanks, I'll ask in what way the Peano curve is not 1-to-1 separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since topologically a disc and a square are the same, most of what you might want to know about this falls under the heading of [Space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).  To summarize, the answer to your main question is that the disc $D^2$ is the image of the interval $[0,1]$ under a continuous map, but not a one-to-one (non-intersecting) continuous map.  So it depends on exactly what you mean by curve.

Comment: Is there an explicit version of the Peano curve directly for a disk (rather than the usual $[0,1]^2$

Comment: @mitch just make one up or take a homeomorphism from the square to the disk

Comment: @yoyo: OK. Is the obvious 'interpret the cartesian coords as polar coords' homeomorphic?