# Bijection between R and C and continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity

It is true that if $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous on all the domain, then it cannot be bijective?
How can I demonstrate this (or show a counter-example for it)?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47547/is-there-a-continuous-bijection-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2). It requires some pretty heavy theory AFAIK (I don't know how much analysis you've done)

Comment: What do you denote $R$ and $C$?

Comment: @Bernard almost certainly $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, though perhaps OP will clarify that it's not

Comment: Sorry, obviously i meant real and complex numbers, anyway I edited so now it is more clear

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you very much now it is quite clear :)