# Bijectiive multi-input function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mathematical-modeling, monotone-functions

Is it possible to find a monotonic bijection that takes as input 2 functions with domain non-negative real numbers and outputs a real value?

This is because I was wondering whether it was possible to combine 2 performance measures and maximize their combination.

Comment: "*monotonic bijection that takes...*" I suspect no and suspect this is already asked here before.  "*If it was possible to combine 2 performance measures*" If this is in a programming context, not in a bijective way without information loss.  Recall that there are only finitely many possible numbers representable by a float or whichever standard data type you may be using, implying by pigeonhole principle that two floats being combined into one float would be mapping a space of $n^2$ possibilities into a space of only $n$ possibilities can not be bijective.

Comment: See [Prove or disprove there exists a continuous bijection from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736775/prove-or-disprove-there-exists-a-continuous-bijection-from-mathbb-r2-to?noredirect=1&lq=1).  It should be equivalent to your question.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was just considering whether it was possible to both minimize the mse and maximize the correct sign of the prediction (a sort of accuracy measure) in a regression setting. I guess it is not feasible precisely because of your reasoning.

Comment: What does it mean for a function of two arguments to be monotone?

Comment: @JMoravitz, the OP did not mention continuity, though I suppose they might only be interested in that case.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley if it were monotonic and bijective, wouldn't that imply continuity?

Comment: What does it mean for it to be monotone, I expect that if $X\geq x$ and $Y\geq y$ then $f(X,Y)\geq f(x,y)$

Comment: It has two arguments - for a function with two arguments what is even meant by monotonic?