# Bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^N$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Hi, could you give me an example of a bijection between $\mathbb R^T$ and $\mathbb R$ with $T$ being a positive integer  which is as regular as possible like $C^{\infty}$ or Lipschitz continuous at least?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are there measurable injections between R and R^N then?

Answer (score 3):

There is no injective continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ for $n \geq 2$. Indeed, by contradiction suppose there exists such a map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$; then $\phi(\mathbb{R}^n \backslash\{0\})=\mathbb{R} \backslash \{\phi(0)\}$ shoud be connected.

For examples of bijections, you can see this excellent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183383/36434).

Answer (score 2):

See the related question

[Is it true that a space-filling curve cannot be injective everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43096/is-it-true-that-a-space-filling-curve-cannot-be-injective-everywhere)

That is, any map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^n$ (with $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $n>1$) cannot be both continuous and a bijection.