# Bijective mapping between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

*Please don't sign this as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420571/bijection-between-mathbb-r-and-mathbb-rn?rq=1), they aren't. I am interested about the actual algorithm, not a proof of the existence.*

Does a such mapping exists? I think, it must, because both of them have the same cardinality ($\aleph_1$).

My actual suggestion for a such mapping were simply merge the digits of the real numbers. For example, from $\pi$ and $e$ we could got

$3.1415...$ and $2.7182...$ would lead to $32.17411852...$ .

Although I am not sure it were ok. Maybe a better, clearer solution also exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [existence of a map between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189328/existence-of-a-map-between-mathbb-r2-and-mathbb-r)

Comment: The assertion that $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$ is the continuum hypothesis and is independent of ZFC, we say it has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: Both have the same cardinality, but it may not be $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @Brad No, it is not. I am interested about a clear, simple algorithm, and not the proof of the existence.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes, but I like to have a simple, clean mapping function, and not a proof of that exists (I know that already).

Comment: You should look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr/183383#183383), if you haven't already

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you - although it doesn't give me an answer, it gives very useful information to find for me a better one.

Comment: @PeterHorvath in fact, you can use the answer to build a bijection from $3$ others.  Namely, we can create bijective maps that take us through
$$
\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: How about using Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein to construct an actual bijection, given injections in both directions?

Comment: Take two real numbers in rational representation, and mix them by intertwining. Of course you need to treat cases with 2 different representations by fixing one. Another method is to mix blocks of digits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb {R^N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn)

Comment: @mez No, they aren't. Please, read the first line of the question. Maybe it is enough for a vote change?

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you describe (interleaving the digits) doesn't work, because it maps  $(0.4999999\ldots, 0.99999\ldots)$ to $0.4999\ldots$, but it also maps $(0.50000\ldots, 0.00000)$ to $0.50000\ldots$, which is the same number as $0.4999\ldots$.

Maybe you want to say that we will forbid the use of funny-looking numbers like $0.4999999\ldots$.  No, that does not work, because then there is no pair of numbers that is mapped to $ \frac{81}{198} = 0.409090909\ldots $.

I described in [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr/183383#183383) how to fix this, and at least one different method for constructing an explicit mapping.