# Can integrals of higher dimension be reduced to 1D integrals by space filling curves?

Tags: integration, general-topology, lebesgue-integral

On the Wikipedia page on [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#Integration) I see the following statement:

> Wiener pointed out in The Fourier Integral and Certain of its
>   Applications that space filling curves could be used to reduce
>   Lebesgue integration in higher dimensions to Lebesgue integration in
>   one dimension.

However as pointed out on this page at 
[Is it true that a space-filling curve cannot be injective everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43096/is-it-true-that-a-space-filling-curve-cannot-be-injective-everywhere)
spacefilling curves are not one-to-one mappings to $\mathbb{R}^2$. So is Wieners statement wrong?

What about the mappings discussed at [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr) . Could such a mapping be used to reduce higher dimensional integrals to lower dimensional ones, if space-filling curves don't work?

Comment: Those maps aren't bijective, either, as the post you quoted admits: decimal expansion isn't unique in all points, $1.000\ldots=0.999\ldots$. Most ignore that, because the set of exceptional points has measure zero (it's countable, actually). So the reduction is possible, but not very practical: the space-filling curve isn't very regular, it's Hölder continuous, but nowhere differentiable, so numerically, those integrals aren't very nice.

Comment: If you are still interested, take a look at Hans Sagan's "Space-Filling Curves".