# Theorem that converts a multiple integral into a single integral?

Tags: integration, soft-question

Forgive me for the vague question. Several years ago, I read about a theorem that (if I remember well) proved what is written in the title. I guess the theorem is from Wiener and it seemed that this theorem was present in his book *"The Fourier integral and certain of its applications".* But I can't find it anywhere. I could be mistaken in my attribution though.

I've been Googling for several days and I couldn't find it. Perhaps I don't remember it too well, perhaps me having to translate from my native language has caused some trouble, etc.

Comment: There are famous examples related to physics and Maxwell's equations (Green's theorem, divergence theorem, curl theorem), like the 1-d line integral of current around a closed curve is related to the  2-d integral of magnetic field through the curve.  You can check wikipedia, or a coffee mug, for Maxwell's equations.  The Cauchy integral formula is also in this genre.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I know them. But it was something bigger, I guess. It was about any number of integrals could be transformed into a single integral.

Comment: If $\int_0^1 g_i(x)dx = m_i$ for $i \in \{1, …, n\}$ then $$\int_0^n\left[\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x-i+1)1_{\{x \in [i-1, i) \}}\right]dx=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i$$ =)

Comment: @Michael I guess I found it! Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436463/can-integrals-of-higher-dimension-be-reduced-to-1d-integrals-by-space-filling-cu).

Comment: Aha.  I see that link has an unanswered question.  If space-filling curves can be (in principle) used, I doubt they would make anything easier.

Comment: @Michael Yes. It seems there are more details about it on Hans Sagan's _"Space-Filling Curves"_.