# Intuition behind a proof showing a square is homeomorphic to a quotient of an interval

Tags: general-topology, intuition

There's a rather simple proof for the following theorem:

> There exists an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ such that the quotient $I/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the unit square $I^2$.

We first form a surjective map $f\colon I\to I^2$ which is known to exist by several constructions. We then define $x\sim y$ for $x,y\in I$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$. The corresponding map $\tilde{f}\colon I/{\sim}\to I^2$ is then, by construction, a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space and so is a homeomorphism.

My question is in trying to get some kind of intuition for this equivalence $\sim$ if at all possible. Given the usual complexity in the definition of space filling curves, it seems like this might be a daunting task. I wonder if anyone could offer some insight - perhaps even just how large the preimage sets under $f$ can be, as I'm not even sure if these sets are finite. If these preimage sets are infinite, then I assume they are either densely embedded in $I$ or have the structure of a Cantor set - does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Are you sure that $I/\sim$ is compact?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Sure, the continuous image of a compact space is compact. The quotient map $x\mapsto [x]_{\sim}$ is the continuous map.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a highly non-constructive proof. The only "free parameter" is the choice of space-filling curve, and there are explicit examples of those.

Comment: @ZhenLin True. That was a poor choice of words.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29743/3457

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen That does seem relevent indeed. So it looks like there are uncountably many non-injective points and the preimage of any one such point is either $2,3$ or $4$ elements in $I$.