# Is there a hilbert curve equivalent for circles?

Tags: fractals, curves

Is there a space-filling curve that has the same properties of a hilbert curve (two points close in 1D are close in 2D) but grows in a circular shape instead of a rectangular one?

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/is-there-a-way-to-represent-the-interior-of-a-circle-with-a-curve

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a such curve construction, but the next best thing is probably using a suitable mapping between square and circle disc and then transform the square based hilbert curve onto a circle.

Maybe something like this: [Conformal mapping circle onto square (and back)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015205/conformal-mapping-circle-onto-square-and-back)